# Merging YAML arrays, ignoring other fields in the YAML

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm looking for a way to merge arrays from two separate YAMLs (appending one to the other). However the YAMLs have a field (not in the arrays) wrapped with `{}` to be replaced with runtime values. i.e

```
# yaml a
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: {clusterRoleName}
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

# yaml b
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: {clusterRoleName}
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]

# desired
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: {clusterRoleName}
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources: ["deployments"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

I'm on yq version 2.14 for this. I've tried `yq merge -a=append a.yaml b.yaml`, which handles the rules arrays as I'd like but treats `name: {clusterRoleName}` as JSON and outputs:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: {ClusterRoleName: ''}
...
```

Is there a way to only merge one field, or ignore a specific key or type of value? I'm also not tied to using yq for this if someone is able to suggest an alternative method.

Comment: Could you upgrade to a much recent version? There are lot of new features in v4

Comment: Upgrading is potentially an option, although this specific use was part of a large project so the ideal was finding a solution that worked with the existing version. If there's a clean way in v4 though would be interested - will check it out thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a dedicated yaml parser such as yq would be ideal using awk maybe an alternative:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR && !/^[[:space:]]/ { tag=$1;next } tag=="rules:" && FNR==NR { map[idx++]=$0 } END { tag="" } NR!=FNR && !/^[[:space:]]/ { if (tag=="rules:") { for (i in map) { print map[i]}} tag=$1 } NR!=FNR { print }' yamlb yamla
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'NR==FNR && !/^[[:space:]]/ { # Processing yamlb (NR==FNR) and there there are spaces at the beginning of the line
         tag=$1; # Set the variable tag to the first space delimited field
         next # Skip to the next file
        } 
     tag=="rules:" && FNR==NR { # Process where tag is "rules:" and we are processing yamlb
          map[idx++]=$0 # Put the line in an array map with in incrementing index
        } 
     END { 
          tag="" # At the end of the file reset the variable tag
        } 
     NR!=FNR && !/^[[:space:]]/ { # Process yamla where there are no spaces at the start of the line
          if (tag=="rules:") { 
            for (i in map) { 
               print map[i] # If tag is equal to rules: print the array map
            }
          } 
          tag=$1 # Set the variable tag to the first space delimited field.
         } 
      NR!=FNR { 
          print # Print lines when we are processing yamla
         }' yamlb yamla
```

Comment: Thanks! This is really cool - in the end I was able to use a combination of sed and yq to workaround the template values, appreciate you taking the time to write this as was interesting to read and try out. :)